# Actionscript Byte Arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I am writing alot of single bytes into a byte Array. Is there any way to compact this and write them all at once?

```
myByteArray.writeByte(0x00);
myByteArray.writeByte(0x00);
myByteArray.writeByte(0x00);
myByteArray.writeByte(0x01);
myByteArray.writeByte(0x00);
myByteArray.writeByte(0x10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could create a `Vector` and list your values there, then just write them in from there.

```
var values:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10];

for each(var i:uint in values)
{
    myByteArray.writeByte(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ByteArray does not support `[]` notation. The only thing, that comes to my mind is the following:

```
var myByteArray:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
var tempArr:Array=[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10];
for each (var elem:int in tempArr)
    myByteArray.writeByte(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you are doing this a lot, is to create a file that has the sequence of bytes that you want, embed that file into your swf as a byte array, and then use [`.writeBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeBytes%28%29). Something like:

```
[Embed(source="data.dat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private const Fragment:Class;
```

And then:

```
var wad:ByteArray = new Fragment() as ByteArray;
myByteArray.writeBytes(wad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to vote this down, as this is utterly ridiculous :).

```
myByteArray.writeUnsignedInt(0x00 << 24 | 0x00 << 16 | 0x00 << 8 | 0x01);
```

You would save 3 function calls :)